# How to link Subversion trunk and branches to project in Redmine?

Tags: svn, redmine

We are looking at using Redmine, and I've run into a bit of a wall. We're using subversion and have code for each project both in the "trunk" and "branches" folders of the repo.

I've set up the repository link in Redmine to the trunk of each project, but I do not see any way to also link the branches in.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Move to git?  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue is. You can either

1. provide just the SVN repository URL (without sub-structures like *trunk*), e.g.

   `http://your-server/svn`
2. provide multiple repository URLs for each sub-structure, e.g.

   `http://your-server/svn/trunk,
    http://your-server/svn/branches,
    http://your-server/svn/tags`

   see: [redmine issue 779](http://www.redmine.org/issues/779)

We have used both options successfully.